# Regular Expression pattern does not match my requirements

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

I need a regular expression to check that an input can contain only digits,but cannot be 0, the number should be a digit between 1 and 12 digits.
So far I have tried that:

```
data-ng-patern="/^[1-9]{1,12}$/"
```

However doing that I don't allow 0 in any case so for example the input 120, would not match my pattern.

How can I accomplish that?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You dont want a zero anywhere in your input ? or you dont want a number that starts with zero but can have it anywhere else ?

Comment: No, I don't mind having 0 anywhere in the value, what I don't want is the value to be exactly 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must  use `/^[1-9][0-9]{0,11}$/`

Please have a look at the [working demo](https://regex101.com/r/bQ0uC3/1).

```
Input:
0
123
120
023

Matches:
123
120
```

Comment: thanks but didn't work, it stills allow me to enter '0' as an input

Comment: Have a look at the demo. It looks OK, `0` is not matched. Or should '023' be allowed?